# Detect if code using NodeJS specific global objects, what may not exist in browser

Tags: node.js, unit-testing

My code was written in in NodeJS, but It can also work in browser. But I made mistake earlier when I tried read `process.versions` variable directly.

Is there way write test in NodeJS and test am I using some node specific global objects or variables ?

Test has to fail since `process` variable is not defined in browser. But when I did search, Google gives me tutorials "How run my tests in browser", but I am not fan of that idea, I would love to stay in NodeJS. I think maybe some wrapper what hides those node specific global variables. Most likely someone has dome something like that, but google wasn't big help.

I am using mocha for testing, but I am open for suggestions.

Comment: Your most reliable unit test for a browser would be to actually run it in a browser.  Anything else is a simulation prone to errors or omissions in the testing (as you just found).  You can run it programmatically in a browser using the chromium engine and driven from nodejs using something like [puppeteer](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer).  Short of that, you'd have to somehow document all the possible global objects in nodejs and find some way to detect their use or turn their use into an error.  Not easy and subject to constant maintenance issues.

Comment: I understand best browser testing is actually browser and puppeteer is nice choice. I need something what could prevent getting those reference errors in early stage. Sure if code is not executed during tests, I still wont find the culprit until .. later.Thanks for comment